# How to troubleshoot NuGet package installation failure during dependency resolution?

Tags: nuget-package, nuspec

I am working with an application that we deploy through a NuGet package and with the latest version I see the following error:

```
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'MyPackage-2.2.1.alpha-17' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Install-Package : Unable to find a version of 'Antlr' that is compatible with 'MyPackage-2.2.1.alpha-17 constraint: Antlr (= 3.4.1.9004)'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package MyPackage -Version -2.2.1.alpha-17 -Verbose
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
```

In the `MyPackage.nuspec` file metadata we have the following:

```
  <dependencies>
      <dependency id="Antlr" version="[3.4.1.9004]" />
      <!-- and so on -->
```

This is a legit version of Antlr and the dependency seems to be fine. In fact changing the Antlr version doesn't stop the error message and as far as I can judge the problem is caused by another missing reference in the `.nuspec` file but the error message just references the first dependency in the list.

I have tried using the `-Verbose` option ( as the error message shows ) but it just gives me a list of HTTP requests between the various package repositories and my local machine.

I can't figure out how to validate the package or get more information on what is actually going on. *How do I find what dependency is **really** causing the package to fail?*